# pybind11 keeping objects alive

Tags: c++, pybind11

I was studying one of the test files in pybind11 and came across different usages of `keep_alive`.

```
py::keep_alive<1, 2>
py::keep_alive<1, 0>
py::keep_alive<0, 1>
```

Could someone shed light on these usages in this test file? I know the index `0` refers to the return, `1` to `this` pointer. I can only make sense of `py::keep_alive<1, 2>` (using the documentation) but not of its usage in this test file.

```
class Child {
public:
    Child() { py::print("Allocating child."); }
    Child(const Child &) = default;
    Child(Child &&) = default;
    ~Child() { py::print("Releasing child."); }
};
py::class_<Child>(m, "Child")
    .def(py::init<>());

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() { py::print("Allocating parent."); }
    ~Parent() { py::print("Releasing parent."); }
    void addChild(Child *) { }
    Child *returnChild() { return new Child(); }
    Child *returnNullChild() { return nullptr; }
};
py::class_<Parent>(m, "Parent")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def(py::init([](Child *) { return new Parent(); }), py::keep_alive<1, 2>())
    .def("addChild", &Parent::addChild)
    .def("addChildKeepAlive", &Parent::addChild, py::keep_alive<1, 2>())
    .def("returnChild", &Parent::returnChild)
    .def("returnChildKeepAlive", &Parent::returnChild, py::keep_alive<1, 0>())
    .def("returnNullChildKeepAliveChild", &Parent::returnNullChild, py::keep_alive<1, 0>())
    .def("returnNullChildKeepAliveParent", &Parent::returnNullChild, py::keep_alive<0, 1>());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In real code, the `addChild` function would be implemented by having the `Parent` object store to pointer, without taking ownership (i.e. it would not later delete it on the C++ side). What `py::keep_alive<1, 2>` does, is put a reference from the `Parent` object onto the `Child` object passed into `addChild`, thus tying the lifetime of the `Child` to that of the `Parent`.

So, if writing:

```
p = Parent()
p.addChild(Child())
```

then without `keep_alive`, that temporary `Child` object would go out of scope (ref-count down to zero) on the next line. Instead, with `keep_alive<1, 2>`, the following happens (pseudo code):

```
p = Parent()
c = Child()
p.__keep_alive = c
p.addChild(c)
del c
```

So now when `p` goes out of scope, its data gets cleaned up, incl. the `__keep_alive` reference, at which point `c` gets cleaned up as well. Meaning, `p` and the "temporary" child `c` go out of scope at the same time and not earlier.

**EDIT**: For `keep_alive<0, 1>`, the lifetime of the implicit `this` is tied to the return value. In the test it's only used to verify that that policy can work with a None return, but it is common when accessing an internal data item of a temporary, typically do deal with intermediate temporaries on a long statement, like so:

```
c = getCopyOfData().at(0).getField('f')
```

At issue is that in C++, the lifetime of temporaries is until the end of the statement, so the above will be common in transliterated code. But in Python, it ends with the ref-count going 0. Iow., the result of `getCopyOfData()` will disappear after the call `at(0)` finishes, leaving `getField()` point into deleted memory. Instead, with `keep_alive<0, 1>`, it would be (pseudo-code):

```
d = getCopyOfData()
at0 = d.at(0)
at0.__keep_alive = d
del d
c = at0.getField('f')
c.__keep_alive = at0
del at0
```

So now the copied container of data `d` will not go out of scope until the reference to the accessed field goes out of scope.

For `keep_alive<1, 0>`, the lifetime of the return value is tied to the implicit `this`. This is useful if ownership is passed to the caller, while the implicit `this` retains a pointer, in effect deferring memory management from C++ to Python. Remember that in pybind11, object identity is preserved, so any call to `returnChildKeepAlive` returning the same pointer will result in the same Python object, not a new one. So in this case (pseudocode):

```
c = p.returnChildKeepAlive()    # with c now owning the C++ object
p.__keep_alive = c
```

If the reference `c` goes first out of scope, `p` will still keep it alive so as not to be stuck with a dangling pointer. If `p` goes first out of scope, `c` will not be affected because it took over ownership (that is, the C++ side will not be deleted). And if `returnChildKeepAlive()` is called a second time, it will return a reference to the outstanding `c`, not a new proxy, thus not affecting the overall lifetime management.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please also comment on `keep_alive<1,0>` and `keep_alive<0,1>`?

Comment: Done; see edit. I was under the impression that the question was mainly about `keep_alive<1, 2>`.

Comment: Thank you, Wim for your time and your complete answer. As a side question, if I compile my python script using `import py_compile` and `py_compile.compile('test.py')`, can I then import `test.cpython-38.pyc` into pybind? Would this enhance the python integration since it is compiled?

Comment: pybind11 forwards the importing to Python, so you wouldn't hand it the `test.pyc` and still only always ever import `test`. If `test.pyc` exists next to `test.py` and is up-to-date (or if you only have `test.pyc` in the first place), it will be loaded in favor of the `.py` file. Pre-compiling only affects startup performance, not integration. If you pre-compile, then only do this during installation: the `.pyc` and `.pyo` files will have the full path of the original source file in it, which leads to confusing tracebacks if either one is ever moved.

Comment: I truly appreciate your help. Very knowledgable. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Wim, could you please review this question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60100922/1227860, whenever you get a chance