# Keeping Python Interpreter Alive Only During the Life of an Object Instance

Tags: python, c++, class

I have defined a class for using python interpreter as follows:

```
class pythonInt
{
public:
    pythonInt(const char* fname) {
        py::initialize_interpreter();
        m_Module = py::module::import(fname);
    }
    ~pythonInt() {
        py::finalize_interpreter();
    }
    py::module m_Module;
    // ... other class members and functions that uses m_Module
};

int main()
{
    pythonInt *p1 = new pythonInt("pybind_test1");
    delete(p1); 

    pythonInt *p2 = new pythonInt("pybind_test1");
    delete(p2); 

    return 0;
}
```

As soon as the class instance is being destructed I get `Access violation reading location` error when it reaches to deleting the instance `_Py_Dealloc(op)`. How can I finalize the interpreter such that I can successfully delete the previously created class instance `p1` and safely create a new class instance `p2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crash is b/c the data member `py::module m_Module;` is created before and destroyed after the constructor/destructor of `pythonInt` is run, so before initialization and after finalization of the interpreter.

pybind11 offers `scoped_interpreter` for the purpose you're seeking and C++ guarantees construction/destruction order for all data members in an access block. So, assuming that you keep all (Python) data together and `pythonInt` has no base class (with Python data members), this would be an option:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;
class pythonInt
{
public:
    pythonInt(const char* fname) {
        m_Module = py::module::import(fname);
    }
    ~pythonInt() {
    }
    py::scoped_interpreter m_guard;
    py::module m_Module;
    // ... other class members and functions that uses m_Module
};

int main()
{
    pythonInt *p1 = new pythonInt("pybind_test1");
    delete(p1);

    pythonInt *p2 = new pythonInt("pybind_test2");
    delete(p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Compared to your example, it adds `#include <pybind11/embed.h>` and `py::scoped_interpreter m_guard;` (where again it is to be stressed that the order is crucial); and it removes the interpreter initialization/finalization.

Comment: Thanks Wim. The code successfully passes `delete(p1)` which is great. However, it stops at `pythonInt *p2 = new pythonInt("pybind_test2");` and gives `error alreary set`.

Comment: The `py::error_already_set` exception's `what()` prints the `str()` of the actual Python exception. So, what does it state in full? If nothing, do a `try {} catch(...){}` around the statement and print the error through `PyErr_Print()`. Most likely there's a Python error in either `pybind_test1` or `pybind_test2` module.

Comment: I am actually passing the same file to both `p1` and `p2` and it throws an exception only on `p2`. The error I get it is: `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE27D0A839 in mypython_test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: pybind11::error_already_set at memory location 0x0000009827F5F9B8`. The returned object `PyObject *obj = PyImport_ImportModule(name);` is `NULL`.

Comment: If `PyImport_ImportModule` returns `NULL`, that means the module can not be found. To simplify testing, use a module that for sure exists, such as eg. `sys`.

Comment: I uploaded the output of `PyErr_Print()` in https://ibb.co/4Y8hT7m. `pybind_test1.py` does exist and is successfully imported by `p1`. Seems like the recalling and re-initializing the interpreter is causing some trouble. What do you think?

Comment: Looks like a reference counting problem in or (in a module used by) `pybind_test1.py`. The error is b/c this predicate `(Py_REFCNT(type) != 0)` fails for the `PyStructSequence` type. Note that the Python interpreter never offloads shared libraries, even if the extension module such library represents is fully removed, so any data objects stick around, and apparently the ref-count isn't properly reduced. Some delta-debugging on `pybind_test1.py`, removing parts to find the offending code, would allow pin-pointing the problematic one (but you may be unable to do anything about it).

Comment: Wim, do you mind reviewing my question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60178439/1227860? I need your help and I would appreciate it.