# Running Pybind11 on a Single Thread

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, pybind11

Is it possible to have pybind11 start a python interpreter on a single thread within C++? I have a class that

1. initializes the interpreter and
2. calls a function in a python script.

I would like to call this function on multiple threads that C++ creates.

```
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace py = pybind11;

class callMyPythonFunctionFromCpp
{
    callMyPythonFunctionFromCpp() { m_module = py::module::import("mypython_script_file"); }

    void myfunc() // trying to call this function on multiple threads.
    { 
        py::object res = m_module.attr("myfunc");
    }

private:
    py::scoped_interpreter m_guard;
    py::module m_module;

};

void thread_function()
{
    callMyPythonFunctionFromCpp m;
    m.myfunc();
    std::cout << "thread function\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(&thread_function);
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strongly depends on what `mypython_script_file` does. Several resources (files, signals, global C variables) remain shared, like in any other threaded program, but with this approach any means of access control is lost as the Python module is unaware of it having been threaded. Some of these problems can be side-stepped by doing an initial import on the main program, allowing C initialization to finish running, before starting any threads.

Comment: Hi Wim, can I have your thoughts on this post, please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60609340/1227860. Truly appreciate it,